# SQL query in Ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query, it says syntax error.But syntax looks good for me.

```
SELECT Errortypereport.[Job Design Control],
       Errortypereport.[Detailer Name], Errortypereport.SuppilerName,
       Errortypereport.[Part Number], Errortypereport.[Change Level],
       Errortypereport.[Event Type Selected], Errortypereport.[Tracking Number],
       Errortypereport.[Event Date], Errortypereport.[Error Type Selected],
       Errortypereport.[Sub Type Selected], Errortypereport.ErrorSubTypeComment,
       Errortypereport.[Fundamental Errors Qty],
       Errortypereport.[Information Errors Qty],
       Errortypereport.[Readability Errors Qty], Errortypereport.[Error Sub Type Ref],
       Errortypereport.Enteredby, Errortypereport.[Wrapper engineer]
FROM Errortypereport INNER JOIN
     POSBLD ON (Errortypereport.Part Number)=(POSBLD.PartNumber)
           And (Errortypereport.Change Level)=( POSBLD.ChangeLevel);
```

error message is:  syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(Errortypereport.Part Number)=(POSBLD.PartNumber)
               And (Errortypereport.Change Level)=( POSBLD.ChangeLevel)'

Comment: I put your query in a code format block.  Could you post the full error message?

Comment: In your select statement you properly select Errortypereport.[Part Number].  But in your ON condition for your join you forgot to add [ ]'s to the fields Part Number and Change Level.  If you have spaces in column names you need to wrap them around [ ]'s.

Comment: @angiee - i noticed this issue is still open, have you resolved it?  If so please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

**If you have spaces in column names you need to wrap them around [ ]'s.**

There is a space between Part and Number in your On as well as change level

```
ON (Errortypereport.Part Number)=(POSBLD.PartNumber) And (Errortypereport.Change Level)=( POSBLD.ChangeLevel);
```

Change it to:

```
ON (Errortypereport.[Part Number])=(POSBLD.PartNumber) And (Errortypereport.[Change Level])=( POSBLD.ChangeLevel);
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
ON Errortypereport.[Part Number]
```

and

```
Errortypereport.[Change Level]
```

Answer (score 3):

If a column name is a reserved word or contains a space; `Errortypereport.Part Number` it must be escaped with `[]` such that you use; `Errortypereport.[Part Number]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some brackets on your `JOIN`.  I would also use a table alias for readability.

```
SELECT 
    E.[Job Design Control], 
    E.[Detailer Name], 
    E.SuppilerName, 
    E.[Part Number], 
    E.[Change Level], 
    E.[Event Type Selected], 
    E.[Tracking Number], 
    E.[Event Date], 
    E.[Error Type Selected], 
    E.[Sub Type Selected], 
    E.ErrorSubTypeComment, 
    E.[Fundamental Errors Qty], 
    E.[Information Errors Qty], 
    E.[Readability Errors Qty], 
    E.[Error Sub Type Ref], 
    E.Enteredby, 
    E.[Wrapper engineer]
FROM Errortypereport E 
INNER JOIN POSBLD 
    ON (E.[Part Number])=(POSBLD.PartNumber) 
        AND (E.[Change Level])=(POSBLD.ChangeLevel);
```